# Merging the results of itertools.product?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am trying to create a list of numbers from `0-9999` using `itertools.product`. I am able to create a list from `0000-9999` by doing the following:

```
numbers = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
itertools.product(numbers,numbers,numbers,numbers)
```

And while I want entries like `0001`, I would also like to get `001`, `01`, and `1`.

What would be the most effective way to include these?  Should I make calls to `itertools.product(numbers,numbers,numbers)` and `itertools.product(numbers,numbers)` and then somehow combine these with the original or is there a cleaner way?

If I should make two other calls and combine, can someone point me towards how this would be done?  I attempted to use `.append()`, but it throws this error:

```
'itertools.product' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a nested listcomp or genexp (reduced in size here for display purposes):

```
>>> numbers = ['0','1','2']
>>> [''.join(p) for n in range(1,4) for p in product(numbers, repeat=n)]
['0', '1', '2', '00', '01', '02', '10', '11', '12', '20', '21', '22', '000', '001', '002', '010', '011', '012', '020', '021', '022', '100', '101', '102', '110', '111', '112', '120', '121', '122', '200', '201', '202', '210', '211', '212', '220', '221', '222']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
list(''.join(subl) for subl in itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.product(numbers, repeat=i) for i in range(1,5)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Performance improvement on existing answers:

```
from itertools import chain, product

list(map(''.join, chain.from_iterable(product(numbers, repeat=i) for i in range(1, 5))))
# Or on Python 3.5+ with additional unpacking generalizations:
[*map(''.join, chain.from_iterable(product(numbers, repeat=i) for i in range(1, 5)))]
```

omitting `list()`/`[*...]` wrapping if you're just iterating the results.

The performance improves significantly (not so much in this case, but dramatically for larger products) on the CPython reference interpreter as (implementation details here):

1. It pushes the vast majority of work to the C layer, avoiding byte code interpreter loop overhead
2. `product` has [an optimization that reuses the result `tuple`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L2189) (including not needing to set the majority of the values in it) if no references exist when the next result is requested. This optimization isn't available to listcomps and genexprs (the loop structure keeps a reference to the resulting `tuple` alive just long enough that a reference exists when it's determining if it can reuse the `tuple` for the next result), but `map(''.join` avoids that (it only holds the reference to the `tuple` long enough to call the mapper function, discarding it before it yields the result of the mapper).

Even in this case, the speedup is significant, percentage-wise, demonstrated with `ipython` microbenchmarks (in this case, on a Linux x64 3.6 install):

```
>>> %timeit -r5 [''.join(p) for n in range(1, 5) for p in product(nums, repeat=n)]
24.9 μs ± 95.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 10000 loops each)
>>> %timeit -r5 list(map(''.join, chain.from_iterable(product(numbers, repeat=i) for i in range(1, 5))))
18.2 μs ± 41.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

As noted, the gains are large only in percentage terms here (~27% runtime reduction); 6.7 μs is pretty trivial in the grand scheme of things. But if the `range` to cover gets larger and/or the set of `numbers` to `product` over gets bigger, it matters more; for `numbers = '0123456789'` and `range(1, 8)`, the reduction is from 2.54 s to 1.67 s; asymptotically the savings appears to be a savings of roughly a third, and when the total cost is measured in seconds, reducing that cost by a third is meaningful.